# In the 2000 Dune miniseries, why are two characters bald and eyebrowless?

Tags: dune, costume

In the *Frank Hebert’s Dune* TV miniseries, there are two characters with no hair or eyebrows. One is a Spacing Guild representative, and the other is a non-speaking minor character, a young woman spy/seductress, undercover in Giedi Prime (and she seems to be friends with Princess Irulan). Why?
The only possible vague reason I can think of is to hint that she might be a Spacing Guild spy.

Comment: I don't think the two are connected. Farrah is a spy for Irulan, not just her friend

Comment: Also, she's not non-speaking, she has 4 lines when she meets Irulan.